# Android Stacked Bars Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library, trying to customize the Stacked Bars.
The objective is to display the differences between 2 currencies.
So suppose this example for January.
Currency #1 = 8;
Currency #2 = 12

The idea is to show in the same bar both values, but instead of sum the 2 values ( 8 + 12) to have the value 8 "in front" and the value 12 "behind". 
So the total high of the bar is the max value.

I tried to do that, extending the BarEntry class, and instead of calculate the sum, just set the max value. But I'm seeing only one bar now (the one with value = 12)

Do you know if this kind of logic is supported? Any advice?

Comment: how did you shown sum ..Please tell me.

Answer (score 12):

Check out the [guide on how to create stacked-bar-charts](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/), as well as the [example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/StackedBarActivity.java).

Create an entry in the stacked-bar-chart in the following way:

```
BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(xValue, new float[] { 8f, 12f });
```

This will create an entry with a total height of 20, consisting of two different values (8 and 12). The "xValue" is the position this bar will show up on the x-axis.

You can use as many entries for the stack (float array) as you want.
If you intend to do only single entries (no stacks), do not use the `BarEntry` constructor that takes a float array, use the one that only takes a single value.

Comment: I was able to do that. Following your example, what I need to do is to show yval2 "behind" yval1, so instead of a bar with height = 20, the bar I'm expecting is height = 12. And in front of that bar, yval1 with height = 8. I was thinking that maybe I could create a yval1 = 8 and yval2 = 12 - yval1, but the problem are the labels with the amounts.

Comment: @Philipp Can I add Third and fourth values like yval3 , yval4 will it work that way

Comment: Any update on this issue? @psabbate were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Jahoda how to get the single stack

Comment: @PhilippJahoda is there a sample for RealmBarDataSet ? I can see there is a constructor

Comment: Yes, have a look [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart-Realm/blob/master/MPChartLib-Realm/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/realm/implementation/RealmBarDataSet.java#L66)