# How to create a BarChart with grouped bars with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

How can i compare two set of data using `BarChart` of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

It should look like this image below:
[image]

I edited a code, I get from a sample project in github.
how can I put together  `100f and 110f` value in one `Xaxis` label `Whole Number`

```
        Score score1 = new Score(100f, 0, "Whole Number");
        mRealm.copyToRealm(score1);
        Score score2 = new Score(110f, 0, "Whole Number");
        mRealm.copyToRealm(score2);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, that can be done quite easily.

What you need is a `BarChart` with multiple `BarDataSets` where each set (in your case) represents one sex (men or women).

- Here is an example of [how to create a BarChart with multiple DataSets](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivityMultiDataset.java)
- Here is an tutorial of [how to use MPAndroidChart with Realm.io](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Realm.io-database-integration)

Example code (without realm.io)

```
    List<String> xValues = ...; // "Denmark", "Finland", ...

    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter(xValues));

    // create 2 datasets 
    BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(valuesMen, "Men");
    set1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(valuesWomen, "Women");
    set2.setColor(Color.RED);

    BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.groupBars(...); // available since release v3.0.0
    chart.invalidate(); // refresh
```

If you need further assistance, here is a [detailed tutorial](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/) on grouped `BarChart` available on the wiki.

If you want to "stack" values in a `BarChart` above each other, you need to create a stacked-barchart: [Android Stacked Bars Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325801/android-stacked-bars-chart)

Comment: Phillipp the constructor of BarData changed! You need to update your code!

Answer (score 27):

Since there has been an update on BarData constructor you need to use following code:

```
BarChart barChart = (BarChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
barChart.setDescription("");
barChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(50);
barChart.setPinchZoom(false);
barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

XAxis xl = barChart.getXAxis();
xl.setGranularity(1f);
xl.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
xl.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return String.valueOf((int) value);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() {
        return 0;
    }
});

YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return String.valueOf((int) value);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() {
        return 0;
    }
});
leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
leftAxis.setSpaceTop(30f);
leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true
barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

//data
float groupSpace = 0.04f;
float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
float barWidth = 0.46f; // x2 dataset
// (0.46 + 0.02) * 2 + 0.04 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"

int startYear = 1980;
int endYear = 1985;
List<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>(); 
List<BarEntry> yVals2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

for (int i = startYear; i < endYear; i++) {
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i, 0.4f));
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(i, 0.7f));
}

BarDataSet set1, set2;
if (barChart.getData() != null && barChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
    set1 = (BarDataSet)barChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
    set2 = (BarDataSet)barChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(1);
    set1.setValues(yVals1);
    set2.setValues(yVals2);
    barChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
    barChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
    // create 2 datasets with different types
    set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "Company A");
    set1.setColor(Color.rgb(104, 241, 175));
    set2 = new BarDataSet(yVals2, "Company B");
    set2.setColor(Color.rgb(164, 228, 251));
    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);
    dataSets.add(set2);
    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
    barChart.setData(data);
}

barChart.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);
barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(startYear);
barChart.groupBars(startYear, groupSpace, barSpace);
barChart.invalidate();
```

That's how it will look like:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi lidox, thank you for your answer. you saved my many days.Can you please help me with labels. how can I set the labels in the center like it is coming in your graph image.  My labels are starting from the 0 index and not coming in middle .  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "interval per group" explanation makes me save a lot of time. Thank you.

Comment: my list has 21 but showing only 7 data can you help me out

Answer (score 19):

Most of the answers I tried either have issues like misaligned, non centered labels or bars getting hidden out of screen space. So after bit of attempts I have a proper working poc.

> Last 4 lines are the most important.

```
    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries3 = new ArrayList<>();

    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(1,989.21f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(2,420.22f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(3,758));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(4,3078.97f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(5,14586.96f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(6,400.4f));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(7,5888.58f));

    barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(1,950));
    barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(2,791));
    barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(3,630));
    barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(4,782));
    barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(5,2714.54f));
    barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(6,500));
    barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(7,2173.36f));

    barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(1,900));
    barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(2,691));
    barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(3,1030));
    barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(4,382));
    barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(5,2714f));
    barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(6,5000));
    barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(7,1173f));

    barEntries3.add(new BarEntry(1,200));
    barEntries3.add(new BarEntry(2,991));
    barEntries3.add(new BarEntry(3,1830));
    barEntries3.add(new BarEntry(4,3082));
    barEntries3.add(new BarEntry(5,214));
    barEntries3.add(new BarEntry(6,5600));
    barEntries3.add(new BarEntry(7,9173));

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"DATA SET 1");
    barDataSet.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
    BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries1,"DATA SET 2");
    barDataSet1.setColors(Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"));
    BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(barEntries2,"DATA SET 3");
    barDataSet1.setColors(Color.parseColor("#e241f4"));
    BarDataSet barDataSet3 = new BarDataSet(barEntries3,"DATA SET 4");
    barDataSet1.setColors(Color.parseColor("#42f46e"));

    String[] months = new String[] {"TYPE 1", "TYPE 2", "TYPE 3", "TYPE 4"};
    BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet,barDataSet1,barDataSet2,barDataSet3);
    barChart.setData(data);

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(months));
    barChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0);
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);

    float barSpace = 0.02f;
    float groupSpace = 0.3f;
    int groupCount = 4;

    //IMPORTANT *****
    data.setBarWidth(0.15f);
    barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
    barChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(0 + barChart.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * groupCount);
    barChart.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace); // perform the "explicit" grouping
    //***** IMPORTANT
```

and the end result I got is:

[image: Bar graph with labels fixed]

Comment: hi Sudesh, will you please update ans with whole code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55386818/7735032 . I have done a POC and provided the source code and apk file, U can check the github link

Comment: Please elaborate how new IndexAxisValueFormatter(months) is working? It doesnt make sense to me. How are the X-Values correspondant to the "months" (Type1, type2, etc)?

Comment: Hi Sidesh, Do you have any idea how to show all 4 type 1 values in marker window together when user click on any where in type 1 section?

Comment: @sudesh it shows warning for `BarData data = new BarData(barDataSet,barDataSet1,barDataSet2,barDataSet3);` class not found exception

Comment: @Sagar either mpAndroidChart dependency wasn't included or there has been an update in the dependency. If you're still facing the issue, check if my sample project works for you https://github.com/sudeshim3/GroupBarGraph and let me know if you are facing any issue.

Answer (score 2):

- Step1 
  Divide first number of groups in bar chart. Like below sample code displaying for 5 groups. Every group have 5 bars in that.

  ```
             xaxis0 = new ArrayList<>();
             for (int i = 0; i < cData.size(); i++) {

                 String str = cData.get(i).get("count");
                 str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
                 String[] finalString = str.split(",");
                 if (i == 0) {
                     for (int k = 0; k < finalString.length; k++) {

                         int data22 = Integer.parseInt(finalString[k]);
                         BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(data22, position);
                         valueSet1.add(v1e1);
                     }
                 }
                 if (i == 1) {
                     for (int k = 0; k < finalString.length; k++) {
                         int data22 = Integer.parseInt(finalString[k] + "");
                         BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(data22, position);
                         valueSet2.add(v1e1);
                     }
                 }
                 if (i == 2) {
                     for (int k = 0; k < finalString.length; k++) {
                         int data22 = Integer.parseInt(finalString[k] + "");
                         BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(data22, position);
                         valueSet3.add(v1e1);
                     }
                 }
                 if (i == 3) {
                     for (int k = 0; k < finalString.length; k++) {
                         int data22 = Integer.parseInt(finalString[k] + "");
                         BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(data22, position);
                         valueSet4.add(v1e1);
                     }
                 }
                 if (i == 4) {
                     for (int k = 0; k < finalString.length; k++) {
                         int data22 = Integer.parseInt(finalString[k] + "");
                         BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(data22, position);
                         valueSet5.add(v1e1);
                     }
                 }
                 xaxis0.add(i, xdata.get(i).get("date"));
  ```
- Step2 In above code you observe that 5 groups of bar entry loading data in loop of every  valueset - ArrayList valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>(); 
  Initialize before this valuesets and
- Step3 And load that 5 sets to Bardataset like below

  ` BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Set1");
    barDataSet1.setColors(whitecolors);
    barDataSet1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

  BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Set2");
    barDataSet2.setColors(whitecolors);
    barDataSet2.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

  BarDataSet barDataSet3 = new BarDataSet(valueSet3, "Set3");
    barDataSet3.setColors(whitecolors);

  barDataSet3.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    BarDataSet barDataSet4 = new BarDataSet(valueSet4, "Set4");

  barDataSet4.setColors(whitecolors);
    barDataSet4.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

  BarDataSet barDataSet5 = new BarDataSet(valueSet5, "Set5");
    barDataSet5.setColors(whitecolors);

  barDataSet5.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
     dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
     dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
     dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
     dataSets.add(barDataSet3);
     dataSets.add(barDataSet4);
     dataSets.add(barDataSet5); `
- Last step need to attached this data to Bardata like below code

BarData data11 = new BarData(xaxis0, dataSets);
data11.setGroupSpace(100f);

```
               holder.chart.setData(data11);

               XAxis xAxis = holder.chart.getXAxis();

               xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

               xAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
```

xAxis.setGridColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

```
               xAxis.isDrawLabelsEnabled();
```

xAxis.setAxisLineColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.accentColor)); 
               xAxis.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

```
               xAxis.isAdjustXLabelsEnabled();

               xAxis.setAdjustXLabels(true);

               holder.chart.setDescription("");

               holder.chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
 holder.chart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
               holder.chart.getAxisRight().setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
               holder.chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
               holder.chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
               holder.chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
               holder.chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
               holder.chart.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
               holder.chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
               holder.chart.setTransitionGroup(true);
               YAxis yAxis = holder.chart.getAxisLeft();
               yAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
               yAxis.setLabelCount(5);
               yAxis = holder.chart.getAxisRight();
               yAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
               yAxis.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
               Legend l =  holder.chart.getLegend();
               l.setEnabled(false);     
               Paint p = holder.chart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_INFO);
               p.setTextSize(10);
               p.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
               p.setTypeface(gotham);
               holder.chart.invalidate();
               l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_CENTER);
               l.setTextSize(200);
               yAxis.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());

   # Thats it if you have doubt about this code ask me any time .......
```