# Unable to resolve constructor when using MPAndroidchart library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to implement a graph to my android application. For that i have used [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library. But there seems to be a constructor error when trying to implement it.

**my xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.paycorp.androidtest.Graph4">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**code**

```
public class Graph4 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BarChart chart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

        BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
        chart.setData(data);
        chart.setDescription("My Chart");
        chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
        chart.invalidate();
    }

    private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v1e1 = new BarEntry(110.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet1.add(v1e1);
        BarEntry v1e2 = new BarEntry(40.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet1.add(v1e2);
        BarEntry v1e3 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet1.add(v1e3);
        BarEntry v1e4 = new BarEntry(30.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet1.add(v1e4);
        BarEntry v1e5 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet1.add(v1e5);
        BarEntry v1e6 = new BarEntry(100.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet1.add(v1e6);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
        BarEntry v2e1 = new BarEntry(150.000f, 0); // Jan
        valueSet2.add(v2e1);
        BarEntry v2e2 = new BarEntry(90.000f, 1); // Feb
        valueSet2.add(v2e2);
        BarEntry v2e3 = new BarEntry(120.000f, 2); // Mar
        valueSet2.add(v2e3);
        BarEntry v2e4 = new BarEntry(60.000f, 3); // Apr
        valueSet2.add(v2e4);
        BarEntry v2e5 = new BarEntry(20.000f, 4); // May
        valueSet2.add(v2e5);
        BarEntry v2e6 = new BarEntry(80.000f, 5); // Jun
        valueSet2.add(v2e6);

        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, "Brand 1");
        barDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
        BarDataSet barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(valueSet2, "Brand 2");
        barDataSet2.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

        dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(barDataSet1);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet2);
        return dataSets;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
        ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        xAxis.add("JAN");
        xAxis.add("FEB");
        xAxis.add("MAR");
        xAxis.add("APR");
        xAxis.add("MAY");
        xAxis.add("JUN");
        return xAxis;
    }
}
```

In this code i get the error in this line

```
BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
```

error comes in getXAxisValues(), getDataSet() part.

The error specifically says this

```
cannot resolve contructor 'BarData(java.util.ArrayList <java.lang.string>, java.util.ArrayList<com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataset>)'
```

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214617/cannot-resolve-constructor-bardata Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried these solutions. didn't work out for me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where do I put X-Axis values, but MPAndroidChart works if you fix them.

from:

```
BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());

private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = null;
    ...
}
```

to:

```
BarData data = new BarData(getDataSet());

private ArrayList<IBarDataSet> getDataSet() {
    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = null;
    ...
}
```

at MPAndroidChart v3.0beta

Comment: yes the error will be gone but when you run the app it will crash. did u actually run this code?

Comment: of course I run that code. I hope you don't delete codes below that `ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = null;`: `getDataSet()` returns `null`? If not, what's the error code?

Comment: This should actually work. Had exactly same problem, but with ILineDataSet

Comment: Ok it works.but now how can i set values for X axis?

Comment: I gave up trying to use MPAndroidChart v3.0beta. use 2.2.5, then sample source code works well with X axis values.