# MPAndroidChart BarChart (Grouped DataSets) not showing all bars

Tags: java, android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart **BarChart (Grouped DataSets)** for showing data of two users. It is showing data but the problem is that its not displaying data on x-axis from start due to which all the bars are not visible.

**Arrays:**

```
String[] title_list = {"Whatsapp", "Visit", "Callback", "Interested"}
int[] title_values_1 = {50, 15, 25, 36};
int[] title_values_2 = {70, 35, 15, 10};
```

**BarChart:**

```
public void LoadBarChart()
    {
        List<BarEntry> barEntries1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < title_list.length; i++) {
            barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(i, title_values_1[i]));
        }

        List<BarEntry> barEntries2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < title_list.length; i++) {
            barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(i, title_values_2[i]));
        }

        BarDataSet dataSet1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries1, "Dataset 1");
        dataSet1.setColors(getColor(R.color.pie_chart_blue));
        dataSet1.setValueTextSize(10f);  /* values size */
        dataSet1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        BarDataSet dataSet2 = new BarDataSet(barEntries2, "Dataset 2");
        dataSet2.setColors(getColor(R.color.pie_chart_red));
        dataSet2.setValueTextSize(10f);  /* values size */
        dataSet2.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        float groupSpace = 0.06f;
        float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
        float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSet1, dataSet2);
        ValueFormatter vf = new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) { return ""+(int)value; }
        };
        data.setValueFormatter(vf);
        data.setValueTextSize(12f);
        data.setBarWidth(barWidth);

        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                return title_list[(int) value];
            }
        });
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        xAxis.setLabelCount(title_list.length);

        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.groupBars(0f, groupSpace, barSpace);
        barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
        barChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
        barChart.animateY(1000);
        barChart.invalidate();
    }
```

[image]

I have tried answers on stackoverflow but nothing resolved my issue. Kindly help!

**UPDATE**:

After Shayan answer all bars are now visible but labels are not centered.
[image]

Is it possible to center the lables with the bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to achieve the desired result by the guidance of Shayan. I have added few attributes in the answer.

**Spacing and Bar Width:**

```
float groupSpace = 0.15f;
float barSpace = 0.01f; // x2 dataset
float barWidth = 0.42f; // x2 dataset
```

**Addition at X-Axis:**

```
xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
xAxis.setGranularity(1);
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
xAxis.setAxisMaximum(title_list.length);
```

**Formatter:**

```
barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(title_list));
```

So bar chart method now looks like this:

```
public void LoadBarChart()
{
    List<BarEntry> barEntries1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < title_list.length; i++) {
        barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(i, title_values_1[i]));
    }

    List<BarEntry> barEntries2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < title_list.length; i++) {
        barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(i, title_values_2[i]));
    }

    BarDataSet dataSet1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries1, Global.employeesComparisonList.get(0).getName());
    dataSet1.setColors(getColor(R.color.blue));
    dataSet1.setValueTextSize(10f);  /* values size */
    dataSet1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    BarDataSet dataSet2 = new BarDataSet(barEntries2, Global.employeesComparisonList.get(1).getName());
    dataSet2.setColors(getColor(R.color.red));
    dataSet2.setValueTextSize(10f);  /* values size */
    dataSet2.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    float groupSpace = 0.15f;
    float barSpace = 0.01f; // x2 dataset
    float barWidth = 0.42f; // x2 dataset

    BarData data = new BarData(dataSet1, dataSet2);
    ValueFormatter vf = new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) { return ""+(int)value; }
    };
    data.setValueFormatter(vf);
    data.setValueTextSize(12f);
    data.setBarWidth(barWidth);

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(title_list.length);
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)
    xAxis.setGranularity(1);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(title_list.length);

    Legend l = barChart.getLegend();
    l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
    l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);

    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.groupBars(0f,groupSpace,barSpace);
    barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(title_list));
    barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    barChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    barChart.animateY(1000);
    barChart.invalidate();
}
```

**Final Result:**

[image]

Comment: The most important part here for grouping data is the `formula for spacing and bar width`.  In the documentation on setting data it gives it as `// (barSpace + barWidth) * dataSetCount + groupSpace = 1.00 -> interval per "group"`.  Just make sure you adjust this formula for each added complete dataSet and all labels will always show.  Unlike the LineChart there cannot be gaps for BarChart grouped data and if you only have one dataSet do not group data.

Answer (score 2):

You have to play with the spacings, I think when its unable to adjust the whole thing in the screen it starts cutting bars.

Add this line so bars may start from the begining

```
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)
```

Setting spacing and widths a bit low like this

```
    float groupSpace = 0.06f;
    float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
    float barWidth = 0.40f; // x2 dataset
```

The complete method will look something like this

```
public void LoadBarChart()
{
    List<BarEntry> barEntries1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < title_list.length; i++) {
        barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(i, title_values_1[i]));
    }

    List<BarEntry> barEntries2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < title_list.length; i++) {
        barEntries2.add(new BarEntry(i, title_values_2[i]));
    }

    BarDataSet dataSet1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries1, "Dataset 1");
    dataSet1.setColors(R.color.colorPrimary);
    dataSet1.setValueTextSize(10f);  /* values size */
    dataSet1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    BarDataSet dataSet2 = new BarDataSet(barEntries2, "Dataset 2");
    dataSet2.setColors(R.color.colorPrimary);
    dataSet2.setValueTextSize(10f);  /* values size */
    dataSet2.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    float groupSpace = 0.06f;
    float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
    float barWidth = 0.40f; // x2 dataset

    BarData data = new BarData(dataSet1, dataSet2);
    ValueFormatter vf = new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) { return ""+(int)value; }
    };
    data.setValueFormatter(vf);
   // data.setValueTextSize(12f);
    data.setBarWidth(barWidth);

    XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            return title_list[(int) value];
        }
    });
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(title_list.length);
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.groupBars(0f,groupSpace,barSpace);
    barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    barChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    barChart.animateY(1000);
    barChart.invalidate();
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: thanks for the answer but now whatsapp item is showing twice on x-axis

Comment: Labels are also not aligned with the bars. Any suggestion?

Comment: try setting granularity to 1

Comment: Duplicate issue is now resolved. Is it possible to center the label with the bars?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done quite easily.

What you need is a `BarChart` with multiple `BarDataSets` where each set (in your case) represents count of each activity.

- Here is an example of [how to create a BarChart with multiple DataSets](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivityMultiDataset.java)
- Here is an tutorial of [how to use MPAndroidChart with Realm.io](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Realm.io-database-integration)

Example code (without realm.io)

```
    List<String> xValues = ...; // "Denmark", "Finland", ...

    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter(xValues));
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);

    // create 2 datasets 
    BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(valuesMen, "Men");
    set1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(valuesWomen, "Women");
    set2.setColor(Color.RED);

    BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2);
    chart.setData(data);
    chart.groupBars(...); // available since release v3.0.0
    chart.invalidate(); // refresh
```

If you need further assistance, here is a [detailed tutorial](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/setting-data/) on grouped `BarChart` available on the wiki.

If you want to "stack" values in a `BarChart` above each other, you need to create a stacked-barchart: [Android Stacked Bars Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325801/android-stacked-bars-chart)

**

> Result Image

[image]

**

Comment: Is there a way to center the lables with the bars. After shayan's answer bars are showing but labels are not centered.

Comment: have you Tried this......xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);